# Simulate the assignment of function arguments to *args and **kwargs

Tags: python

Is there a simple way to "simulate" the assignment of arguments to function parameters?

Say I have a function

```
def fn(a, b, c='default', *args, **kwargs):
    print(f'a={a}, b={b}, c={c}')
    print(f'args={args}')
    print(f'kwargs={kwargs}')
```

and I call it the following way:

```
>>> args = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> kwargs = {'extra_kw': 5}
>>> fn(*args, **kwargs)
a=1, b=2, c=3
args=(4,)
kwargs={'extra_kw': 5}
```

I want to extract what `args` and `kwargs` will be in the function `fn`, without calling `fn`.

Basically, I am trying to write a function that takes as input a function and a list and dict of arguments and returns the extra `args` and `kwargs`:

```
def extract_extra_args_and_kwargs(f, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

The expected outcome for the example would be:

```
>>> extract_extra_args_and_kwargs(fn, args, kwargs)
((4,), {'extra_kw': 5})
```

I have tried playing around with `inspect.signature`, but given that Python itself must resolve this assignment somewhere I was hoping that I can directly access the corresponding function.

Comment: Maybe you have it the way you want it, but you also might want your function to be `fn(a, b, *args, c='default', **kwargs)`

Comment: True, although this was just a basic example with no relevance to my actual code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that `inspect.getcallargs` has been deprecated since Python 3.5, per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getcallargs).

Use `inspect.signature.bind` instead going forward:

```
from inspect import signature

def extract_extra_args_and_kwargs(f, *args, **kwargs):
    sig = signature(f)
    bound = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
    return bound.arguments['args'], bound.arguments['kwargs']

def fn(a, b, c='default', *args, **kwargs):
    print(f'a={a}, b={b}, c={c}')
    print(f'args={args}')
    print(f'kwargs={kwargs}')
args = (1, 2, 3, 4)
kwargs = {'extra_kw': 5}
print(extract_extra_args_and_kwargs(fn, *args, **kwargs))
```

This outputs:

```
((4,), {'extra_kw': 5})
```

Answer (score 7):

This is `inspect.getcallargs`:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def fn(a, b, c='default', *args, **kwargs):
...   pass
...
>>> inspect.getcallargs(fn, 1,2,3,4, extra_kw=5)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'args': (4,), 'kwargs': {'extra_kw': 5}}
```

Your `extract_extra_args_kwargs` as defined in your question would be a simple wrapper.

```
def extract_extra_args_kwargs(fn, args, kwargs):
    x = inspect.getcallargs(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    return x['args'], x['kwargs']
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks :)